# Terminal: cp -r -u command does not recursively copy folder contents to another folder

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, command

I have two folders that hold files and folders, some of which have the same names. So, for example: FolderA holds File1, File2 and Folder3, whilst FolderB holds File1, File2, Folder3 and File 4.

I want to recursively copy the contents of FolderB into FolderA, skipping existing files, so that FolderA ends up with: File1, File2, Folder3 and File 4. The only new files added would be File4 and whatever non-existing files there were inside Folder3.

I thought the command would be: cp -R -n /directory/to/FolderA /directory/to/FolderB

without any trailing slashes. However, when I do this I just end up copy pasting FolderB into FolderA, so that FolderA holds: File1, File2, Folder3 and FolderB.

Where am I going wrong, and how should I properly write this command?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the content of `FolderB` into `FolderA`:

```
cp -r -n FolderB/* FolderA
```

Comment: i did cp -r -n FolderB/ FolderA   and that seemed to work fine. what is the difference between this command and that which you wrote, which includes a * ?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. * just stands for "everything".